# HighCharts draw custom line segment annotation

Tags: highcharts

Current highcharts support free drawing of a line segment annotation. But I want to be able to draw  a line based on the data points on the chart series. Basically I want to implement:

1. click on first point in the chart series to select the first data point
2. click on the second point on the chart to select the second data point
3. draw a line segment with those two data points
4. I should be able to edit the segment just like current highcharts annotations. The edit dialog should show line segment option plus two data points which I can edit.

Any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7xvr85wt/

Select two points by clicking on them & holding the shift, next click on the button. Is that an output that you want to achieve? Now, what do you want to add to this segment line?

```
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  series: [{
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175],
    allowPointSelect: true,
  }]
});

function drawPath(points) {
  points.length = 2;
  const x1 = points[0].plotX + chart.plotLeft,
    x2 = points[1].plotX + chart.plotLeft,
    y1 = points[0].plotY + chart.plotTop,
    y2 = points[1].plotY + chart.plotTop;

  chart.renderer.path(['M', x1, y1, 'L', x2, y2])
    .attr({
      'stroke-width': 2,
      stroke: 'red'
    })
    .add();
}

const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const selectedPoints = [];
  chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
    if (p.selected) {
      selectedPoints.push(p);
    }
  })

  drawPath(selectedPoints);
});
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

Comment: Sebastian, thanks a lot for the answer. The line draws correctly between two points. But the problem is that it cannot be edited. What I wanted to achieve is similiar to the line segment annotation. You can drag the start/end point to new data points and you can click on the line to edit the style (like color/fill) as well as save with chart like line segment annotation. BTW, is there any event hook when user select the data point on the chart? Your code perfectly demonstrated how to use renderrer function and it is a perfecdt start point. Thanks again.

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/stock-tools-custom-gui see the above example. you can draw line segment  annotation from lines -> segment menu, it will draw first point then second point and finally draw a line. You can edit the line by clicking it. You can also drag the start/end point with your mouse. finally you can save the annotation (to localStorage I believe) along with the chart.

Comment: Actually, why can't you use the segment annotation from the stock-tools for it? Back to your question -  here you can find the select callback: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events.select